# Tailwind Classes not compiled using ViewComponents Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tailwind-css, view-components

I can use Images in post if you want read all post with images go to github issues
https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/issues/201

I have been testing ViewComponts and I found this ViewComponts + Tailiwnd guide.

Example
The guide uses a CDN to use tailwind and everything works fine.

My problem is that using tailwindcss-rails the tailwind classes that are injected from a component are not rendered in the view.

I start server from Procfile

Error:

Classes are loaded in Html but not in css

I know where the error is but I can't find a solution without having to use a tailwind CDN.

PD: I have also used rails assets:clobber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add the components folder in the paths array to `Tailwind` config

###### config/tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}',
    './app/components/**/*' //This is the new Entry
  ],

...
```